# Is there any addons for Visual Studio for serialising XML documents?

Tags: xml, serialization

When working with JSON, I can use NuGet to add JSON.Net and this allows me to create a class containing the elements of my JSON object and serialise this to a JSON string. This seems to work better than using `String.Format("");` to just manually create the JSON.

For XML, I currently use XDocument to create any XML documents I need to. This works but it is quite a manual process which gets messy as the document gets larger. It is also difficult to maintain when I need to go back later and add to the document.

I have a hunch that I find this difficult and messy because I'm doing it wrong. I am creating my XML documents using functional concepts but am working with an Object Oriented language. Surely what I need to do is create an class and implement properties and a constructor to create an object with the same properties as the XML document, then use some sort of framework to serialise this to a string?

So my question is how do I serialise a class to XML using Visual Studio 2010 and C#?

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking here? How to serialize a class to XML?

Comment: Yeah, do I need to update the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simply C# class with the needed properties and decorate it with the different `Data*` attributes from the [`System.Runtime.Serisalization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.aspx) namespace then use the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) to produce the XML.

See [Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) on MSDN and the example on the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) page.